# Hold the Fragment state after the rotation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, onsaveinstancestate

I have a fragment with `ViewPager`. I'm trying to save the information which tab was selected so that it can be retrieved correctly when rotating screen. This is my code:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    var currentPage: Int = 0

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        Log.e("DEBUGGING", "onViewCreated: savedInstanceState = $savedInstanceState")
        savedInstanceState?.getInt("currentPage")?.let{
            Log.e("DEBUGGING", "onViewCreated: it = $it")
            currentPage = it
        }
        setViewPagerWithTabs()
    }


    private fun setViewPagerWithTabs() {
        val arrayListOfScreens = arrayListOf<TabScreen>()
        arrayListOfScreens.add(
            TabScreen(
                TodayFragment(),
                getString(R.string.today),
                R.drawable.ic_baseline_wb_sunny_24
            )
        )
        arrayListOfScreens.add(
            TabScreen(
                ForecastFragment(),
                getString(R.string.forecast),
                R.drawable.ic_baseline_event_24
            )
        )

        view_pager.adapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(arrayListOfScreens, childFragmentManager)
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(view_pager)
        Log.e("DEBUGGING", "setViewPagerWithTabs: currentPage = $currentPage")
        view_pager.currentItem = currentPage
        view_pager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                Log.e("DEBUGGING", "onPageSelected: position = $position")
                currentPage = position
            }

            override fun onPageScrolled(
                position: Int,
                positionOffset: Float,
                positionOffsetPixels: Int
            ) {
            }

            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {}
        })

        // setup icons
        var index = 0
        arrayListOfScreens.forEach {
            tabs.getTabAt(index)?.setIcon(it.icon)
            index++
        }
    }


    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        outState.putInt("currentPage", currentPage)
        Log.e("DEBUGGING", "onSaveInstanceState: currentPage = $currentPage")
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }
}
```

These are results of logs when rotating:

```
E/DEBUGGING: onPageSelected: position = 1
E/DEBUGGING: onSaveInstanceState: currentPage = 1
E/DEBUGGING: onViewCreated: savedInstanceState = null
E/DEBUGGING: setViewPagerWithTabs: currentPage = 0
```

I have no idea why the state is not saved... I tried also using `onViewStateRestored()` but the result was exactly the same.

This is how the MainFragment is called in MainActivity:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (!mainViewModel.hasCurrentData() && !mainViewModel.internetAvailable()) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, NoDataFragment())
                .commitNow()
        } else {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment())
                .commitNow()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your activity seems to be unconditionally replacing whatever fragment was restored from `savedInstanceState`, instead of checking `if (savedInstanceState == null)`. What of that logic do you need to run?

Comment: oh, that's it!!!! Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, take a look at [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) to retain data across configuration changes without serializing it. Although keep in mind that `ViewModel` itself won't help with process death the way `onSaveInstanceState()` does. You'd need a [SavedStateHandle](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/SavedStateHandle) for that.